# Get address family from socket. Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, network-programming

I want to write a C++ wrapper for the Linux Socket API. In the socket() ctor the adress family (AF) is requested. I dont want to require the AF in the connect() signature again, becuase it has been already given in the constructor of socket. So how do I get the AF from an existing socket?

Comment: Remember the address family in a member variable of your wrapper ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Damn. Searched about half an hour. Now after posting this question I found immiediately the answer.

[getsockopt([...])](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html) with option SO_DOMAIN (see [socket options](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html))

Comment: Be careful with this option though, as it seem to be Linux specific. If you are writing a wrapper-class can't you just simply save the type as a member variable?

Answer (score 7):

POSIX-standard getsockname will help:

```
int getsockname(int socket, struct sockaddr *restrict address,
       socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

it will fill in given struct sockaddr (upon success):

```
struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short    sa_family;  // <- that's what you looking for
    char              sa_data[14];  
}
```

Comment: Apparently it [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55442633/getsockname-always-return-structure-with-protocol-family-0/55445415#55445415) on Linux.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov getsockname() works just fine, when used properly. Just make sure the socket is bound first.