# getsockname always return structure with protocol family 0

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

`getsockname` always seem to fill `storage` with a structure that has family set to zero which implies that protocol is unspecified.

```
void print_address_attached_to_socket(int socket) {
    socklen_t socket_length;
    struct sockaddr_storage storage;
    int returncode = getsockname(socket, (struct sockaddr *) (&storage), &socket_length);
    if (returncode != 0) {
        perror("Errror getting sock name");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (storage.ss_family == 0) {
        std::cout << "Family is unspecified getsockname failed without telling why..." << std::endl;
        return;
    } else {
        struct sockaddr *sock_addr = (struct sockaddr *) &storage;
        char host[128] = {0}, serv[128] = {0};
        returncode = getnameinfo(sock_addr, socket_length, host, 128, serv, 128, NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
        if (returncode != 0) {
            printf("Errror getting resolving name");
            exit(1);
        }
        std::cout << "Host: " << host << ":" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This function is called after connect and before close.

Example usage: https://gist.github.com/Hajto/09058b335b2466033f96a9a1adfebef4
client.cpp: Code that calls above fragment that supposed get info about host connected to socket
server.cpp: since the code is used the code is used in client I also attached server to enable running the client.

Comment: If you would like for someone to investigate your question, you need to add a [mcve] that anyone can compile and run, and observe the same results as you claim. It's not a lot of work to write a few more lines to call `socket()` and `connect()` to a sample port; but if you would like for someone to take their time to look into your issue, the least you can do is spend a little of time in preparing a [mcve] so that others won't.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov Why is this happening, is this normal behaviour? how to fix this behaviour?

Comment: A likely cause of the problem is that the `socket_length` argument-by-reference to `getsockname` is an **input/output** argument, but this program does not initialise the value of that argument.  `socket_length` should be set to `sizeof storage` before the `getsockname` call is made.  `getsockname` can succeed even if the value of `socket_length` is too small to hold the result, but in that case the address result will be truncated, leaving you with uninitialised data in the result buffer.

Comment: @ottomeister My bad. When I initialized it to size of sockaddr_storage it works like a charm. Thank you very, very, very much! <3