# Get address family from socket OS X

Tags: macos, sockets

Getting address family can be done with [getsockopt()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html) with option SO_DOMAIN (see [socket options](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html)) on linux.
(read [Get address family from socket. Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331610/get-address-family-from-socket-linux))

How do I do the same thing on OS X ?

When using the code that worked on linux on OS X I get

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'SO_DOMAIN'
  int err = getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DOMAIN, &addr_family, &len);
                                         ^
```

so not SO_DOMAIN ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find this out by calling `proc_pidfdinfo()` on your own PID, and requesting `PROC_PIDFDSOCKETINFO`:

```c
#include <libproc.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool socketDomainGet(int socket, int *domain) {
    struct socket_fdinfo info;
    int rc = proc_pidfdinfo(getpid(), socket, PROC_PIDFDSOCKETINFO, &info, sizeof info);
    if (rc <= 0) return false;
    *domain = info.psi.soi_family;
    return true;
}
```

Unlike `getsockname()`, this works even if the socket hasn't been bound yet. Note as well as the domain (`psi.soi_family`), it also can tell you the type (`psi.soi_type`) and the protocol (`psi.soi_protocol`).

Keep in mind though this warning Apple gives in the `libproc.h` header:

```c
/*
 * This header file contains private interfaces to obtain process information.
 * These interfaces are subject to change in future releases.
 */
```

They probably aren't going to break this, but the risk is higher than for more official APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Call `getsockname` and read the address family from the returned address, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13435540/1234111.

Answer (score -5):

use SO_TYPE instead of SO_DOMAIN

in OS X man [GETSOCKOPT(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getsockopt.2.html) says

```
SO_TYPE         get the type of the socket (get only)
```

Comment: `SO_TYPE` retrieves the type of the socket (ie, SOCK_STREAM, etc), not the address family (ie, AF_INET, etc). This is even stated as much in the document you linked to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. Read the man again and this is not the answer. What can I use to solve this ?

Comment: reading /darwin-xnu/bsd/sys/socket.h but have no clue how to get  address family from socket.

Comment: "*this is not the answer*" - which is why this answer should be deleted. "*What can I use to solve this?*" - If `SO_DOMAIN` is not supported, the only other way I know is to use `getsockname()`/`getpeername()`, but that requires the socket to be bound/connected first.